# What values to set for modem simulation in Fiddler

Tags: fiddler

In Fiddler, I can see editing `request-trickle-delay` and `response-trickle-delay` effect the modem simulation, but I am unsure what setting these to say 300 ms actually means. Is this the latency or the simulated bandwidth? Is it possible to set the simulated latency and bandwidth differently?

Comment: That represents 300ms of delay between each 1kb of data sent.

Answer (score 2):

Those flags delay each 1K of the request or response, therefore, they lower the bandwidth, but do not simulate latency. To simulate latency, use [this extension](http://fiddlerdelayext.codeplex.com/).